# HtmlAgilityPack not looping through collection

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a webpage with a collection of div's with the class "messages". I am trying to loop through them and put them into a CSV file, however I cant get the collection to loop properly. Here is the code:

```
string fpath = @"C:\Texts\messages.html";

HtmlDocument page = new HtmlWeb().Load(fpath);

var msgs = page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='message']");

List<string> msgList = new List<string>();
foreach (var msg in msgs)
{
    msgList.Add(msg.InnerHtml);
}
```

The msg stays the same through each iteration of the loop. Any idea why that is?

Edit:

Sample HTML (this is 1 msg. msgs will be a collection of these)

```
<div class="message">
<div class="from"><span class="profile fn">Name</span></div>
<abbr class="time published" title="2012-08-11T07:02:50+0000">August 10, 2012 at 5:02 pm</abbr>
<div class="msgbody">
A message will be here.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should put a sample HTML source.

Comment: Which version of HtmlAgilityPack are you using? Can you show us your HTML as well?

Comment: As Simon says (pun not intended :P) please give us a sample of this html, you can make a Fiddle at JSFiddle.net if that helps.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in just before the foreach, what is the Type of the msgs object? IE, what does page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes return ?

Comment: I copied your code and sample HTML verbatim, aside from modifying the value of fpath and duplicating the sample HTML with different content in each "msgbody" div. Worked fine. There's something you're not telling us.