# Regex formula assistance

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to find a regex formula for these HTML nodes:

first: Need the inner html value

```
<span class="profile fn">Any Name Here</span>
```

second: need the title value

```
<abbr class="time published" title="2012-08-11T07:02:50+0000">August 10, 2012 at 5:02 pm</abbr>
```

third: need the inner html value

```
<div class="msgbody">
Some message here. might contain any character.
</div>
```

I'm fairly new to regex, and was hoping someone could offer me some guidance with this. I'll be using it with C# if that makes a difference.

Edit:

The HTML I'd be pulling this out of would look like this:

```
<div class="message">
<div class="from"><span class="profile fn">Name</span></div>
<abbr class="time published" title="2012-08-11T07:02:50+0000">August 10, 2012 at 5:02 pm</abbr>
<div class="msgbody">
Some message
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can, consider xpath instead of regex for this.

Comment: if you use C# you may want to conside HTMLAgilityPack

Comment: Agreed, the Agility pack is awesome; but if you can trust your HTML, Regex does work quite well. When I say trust, perhaps you know its well formed HTML because it comes from your own XSLT transformation or a template system, or something like that.

Comment: a *regex string* is a *pattern*, not a *formula*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of people are quite dismissive of using Regular Expressions to deal with HTML; However, I  believe that if your HTML is assuredly regular and well formatted then you can use Regex successfully.

If you can't assure then, then I urge you to check out the HTML Agility Pack, it's a library for parsing HTML in C# and works very well.

I'm not on my PC, but I'll edit my answer with a suggested regex for your examples, give you something to try at least.

For this one:

```
<span class="profile fn">Any Name Here</span>
```

Try

```
"<span.*?>(?<span>.*?)</span>"
```

Then you can access this via the Match.Groups("span") property of your regex result.

For the Abbr tag:

```
<abbr class="time published" title="2012-08-11T07:02:50+0000">...snip...</abbr>
```

It's similar

```
"<abbr.*?title=\"(?<title>.*?)\".*?>"
```

And lastly for the div:

```
<div class="msgbody">
Some message here. might contain any character.
</div>
```

Is:

```
"<div.*?>(?<div>.*?)</div>"
```

For this one, you may need to set the Multiline regex option.

The key point is the .*? operator.

Adding the question match turns a greedy match into a look ahead match, it tells the Regex engine to look forwards from the place it finds the match, rather then finding the last match and then working backwards; this is incredibly important for matching in HTML where you will have many Chevrons closing tags.

The big problem you'll get though is, what happens if the inner text or an attribute has an '<' or an '"' character in it?
It's very hard to make Regex only match balanced <>'s and it can't easily not use ones that are in between quotes; this is why the Agility pack is often preferred.

Hope this helps anyway!

Edit:

**How to use named capture groups**

This syntax (?..selector..) tells the Regex engine to encapsulate whatever is between the brackets into a value that can be taken out the actual match object.

So for this HTML

```
<span>TEST</span>
```

You'd use this code:

```
string HTML = "<span>TEST</span>";
Regex r = new Regex("<span>(?<s>.*?)</span>");
var match = r.Match(HTML);

string stuff = match.Groups["s"].Value;
//stuff should = "TEST"
```

If you think you'll have multiple captures then you'd use a variant of this overload:

```
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(HTML))
{
   string stuff = m.Groups["s"].Value;
}
```

This should yield the answer you need.

Comment: I've been using HTMLAgilityPack. The issue I have is I can collect the messages into a collection, however I cannot loop through the collection. It gets stuck on the first entry each time. If you have insight into this, here is the question I posted earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973028/htmlagilitypack-not-looping-through-collection?noredirect=1#comment24516819_16973028

Comment: I've updated my answer here to show you the full regex that might work, but for your other question, we need to see a sample of the HTML that you're trying to process, at least 3 nodes of it would help!

Comment: @RussC "It's very hard to make Regex only match balanced <>'s". No, it's actually impossible to make a regex match balanced brackets. You need at least a context-free grammar to do that.

Comment: These are working almost perfectly. The only issue is, I'd like the value inside of the tags, not the tags as well. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: The named groups "(?<div>.*?)" should only return the contents between the quotes. You need to make sure you're using the Groups property of the match; I'll add the syntax to my answer :)

Comment: +1 for sympathy... and the effort demonstrated in giving this nice answer. But I must admit I'm not a believer of regex parsing HTML.

Comment: In honesty, nor am I in general terms. I do hope that this answer helps some other folks understand how named capture groups work!

Answer (score 0):

If your html is always the same you can use this ugly pattern:

```
"profile fn"[^>]*>(?<name>[^<]+)(?:[^t]+|t(?!itle=))+title="(?<time>[^"]+)(?:[^m]+|m(?!sgbody"))+msgbody">\s*(?<msg>(?:[^<\s]+|(?>\s+)(?!<))+)
```

results are in `m.Groups["name"]`, `m.Groups["time"]`, `m.Groups["msg"]`